# Excel file not saving to the correct path

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following procedure to save my file to a network path:

```
Sub Save_Book()

Dim savePATH As String

savePATH = "\\ftl-store\Departments\HR\HR Reports and Metrics\LOA Reports\BRT Reports"


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=savePATH & sFile, FileFormat:=51

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

However, my procedure is not working correctly.  Its saving the file to the path, but the correct path. It saves the file to here: `\\ftl-store\Departments\HR\HR Reports and Metrics\LOA Reports\BRT Reports"` Thus missing the destination folder.

Instead of saving the file to the path it takes this part:

```
BRT Reports
```

and shows as part of my file name when it saves.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a backslash at the end of `savePATH`.

Comment: You haven't provided a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the trailing backslash:

```
Sub Save_Book()

Dim savePATH As String

savePATH = "\\ftl-store\Departments\HR\HR Reports and Metrics\LOA Reports\BRT Reports\"


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=savePATH & sFile, FileFormat:=51

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I missed that. But perhaps sFile is declared as module variable (yuk)?

Comment: Seems not from the question and the described outcome (folder name is used as the filename)